# int cannot be dereferenced in JavaFX

Tags: string, int, javafx-2, javafx, converters

Why is this label in JavaFX refusing the following string once converted from int

```
final int moonPhase =  m.illuminatedPercentage();
System.out.println("The moon is " + moonPhase + "% full");
System.out.println("The next full moon is on: " + MoonPhaseFinder.findFullMoonFollowing(Calendar.getInstance()));
System.out.println("The next new moon is on: " + MoonPhaseFinder.findNewMoonFollowing(Calendar.getInstance()));

myLabel.setText(moonPhase.toString());
```

I get the following error

```
error: int cannot be dereferenced myLabel.setText(moonPhase.toString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare `moonPhase` as an `Integer`, `int` is a **primitive** type, or use [String.valueOf(int i)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) method to return the string representation of the `int` argument.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `toString()` from `int`. Use `Integer` or write

```
myLabel.setText("" + moonPhase);
```